# Oracle 11 g table diagrams

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have created a database in oracle 11g. and now i want to see table relationship diagrams like we can see in mssql server 2005. 
Can anyone suggest ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle is still catching up on the need to make things easier for developers.  However, they took one step in the right direction in 2010, by making SQL Developer Data Modeler free to use.  This product includes a reverse engineering capability, which allows us to generate table relationship diagrams.  [Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html).